# Is there a way to remove component media files on update?

Tags: component, custom-component

In my Joomla component I have a bunch of Javascript files in `media` that change on update ( basically a compiled Angular app ) and because of the way the system is structured, I need to only have the current files in the folder. However when I install my component as an update, it leaves the old files in the `media/com_mycomponent` folder.

What is the best way to clear out the old files during installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a installer script for your component (com_your_component_name/script.php) and add the following code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class com_your_component_nameInstallerScript
{
  function update($parent) 
  {
    JFile::delete($path.$file)
  } 
}
```

The installer script file allows you to run code when your component is installed, uninstalled, or updated, and also before and after the component is installed.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package